# Firebase images are not loading in puppeteer PDF

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf, image-loading

I want to generate images from the HTML string using Puppeteer. I have created the HTML template as a separate page and loaded the same using puppeteer pdf conversion. Once I load the PDF, it was giving the else data but the images are not loading properly.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const handlebars = require('handlebars');
const path = require('path');

const generateCertificate = async (data, traineeName, trainingPlanTitle) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setContent(data, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
    const pdf = await page.pdf({
        path: `${traineeName}_${trainingPlanTitle}.pdf`,
        format: 'a4',
        landscape: true,
    });
    await browser.close();
    return pdf;
};
```

HTML Code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=MonteCarlo"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <style type="text/css">
            .container {
                position: relative;
                display: flex;
                background: #e7e9eb;

                height: 595px;
                width: 842px;
            }

            .box {
                display: flex;
                background: white;
                height: 501px;
                width: 748px;
                margin: 47px;
                z-index: 1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="{{logoImageURL}}" alt="img" />
                </div>
    <div class="sign">
                    <img src="{{signUrl}}" alt="img" />
                </div>
                <div class="text2">
                    <p style="font-family: Open Sans">
                        Successful completion of the training
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="club">
                    <p style="font-family: Open Sans">{{trainingPlanTitle}}</p>
                </div>

                <div class="text3">
                    <p style="font-family: Open Sans">
                        in the duration of {{startDate}} to {{endDate}} under {{clubName}}
                    </p>
                </div>              
            </div>
            <p class="text6">Powered by Tech Club</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, Puppeteer doesn't load the firebase image, and I am not sure how to point this. Also when I run the html file along the images are properly loading. It is not taking external fonts also.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the above problem by changing '`domcontentloaded`' to '`networkidle0`'

```
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setContent(data, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
```